# Load user control in tab item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am trying to load user control in tab item dynamically but i am unable to do so i am using below code .I have visited various posts also but i have got the  below way please let me know where i am wrong:

**User control:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="welcome" Height="20" Width="70"></Button> 
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewMOdel:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class Usercontrol2ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }

        public Usercontrol2ViewModel()
        {
            Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
            //Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Overview", Content = new OverviewViewModel() }); How to load a usercontrol here if it's in the ItemCollection?
            Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Overview", Content = new UserControl2() });

        }

    }
    public class TabItem
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public object Content { get; set; } // object to allow all sort of items??
    }
}
```

**MainPage:**

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">

            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Usercontrol2ViewModel}">
                    <local:UserControl2></local:UserControl2>
                </DataTemplate>

            </TabControl.Resources>

            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        </TabControl>
```

Comment: Given the fact that we don't see the whole page, or the page's code-behind the first question I must ask is - are you setting the VM as the DataContext anywhere?

Comment: yes i.e behind main page

Comment: @MichaelThePotato i have two tabs and content is loaded from user control..now ii  want  to remove tab2 from button click of tab1..how can i do that???

Comment: A command, and send the desired parameters via CommandParameter.
But do you want the button to specifically remove tab2?
or do you want the button to remove any selected tab?

Comment: can you please provide me some good link or code with you i.e from where i can get this easily ..i am new to mvvm @MichaelThePotato

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

basic commands description.
But I can't really help you unless you answer my previous question.
I don't understand what you're trying to do.
Hope the link helps.
BTW - your sample works for me. what is the result you're getting?
empty screen? exception?

Comment: no i am not setitng vm as datacontext @MichaelThePotato

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118214/discussion-between-michaelthepotato-and-stylishcoder).

Comment: You need to debug your binding.  `ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"` is likely incorrect.  You can use the built in tools in 2015, or use a tool like Snoop to examine the binding at runtime and see what's actually in your DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue below is the solution of code patch that needs to be correct above posted code

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"></Setter>
                </Style>
```